# Hide marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, gmaps.js

I'm working on a site similar to [this.](http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Explorable/)

I need to hide the first marker on the map.

The markers are being added with the following function:

```
function et_add_marker( marker_order, marker_lat, marker_lng, marker_description )
```

And output in numbered order:

```
et_add_marker( 0, 28.764060233517, -81.47733406250012, '<div id="et_marker_0" class="et_marker_info"><div class="location-description"> <div class="location-title"> <h2>Beautiful Stairs</h2> <div class="listing-info"><p>Vacation Spot</p></div> </div> <div class="location-rating"><span class="et-rating"><span style="width: 68px;"></span></span></div> </div> <!-- .location-description --> </div> <!-- .et_marker_info -->' );
et_add_marker( 1, 37.80002992748194, -122.43711189453137, '<div id="et_marker_1" class="et_marker_info"><div class="location-description"> <div class="location-title"> <h2>San Francisco Bay</h2> <div class="listing-info"><p>Vacation Spot</p></div> </div> <div class="location-rating"><span class="et-rating"><span style="width: 85px;"></span></span></div> </div> <!-- .location-description --> </div> <!-- .et_marker_info -->' );
```

I have tried different variations of this code to hide the first one:

```
if(marker_order === 0){
    marker.setVisible(false);
}
```

But so far have only been successful in hiding all of the markers or just the last few. I really only need to hide the very first marker. I think I am close to solving this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the markers objects and then, further, call setVisibile method on each

```
var myMarkers = et_add_marker(...);
myMarkers[i].setVisible(false);
```

In the follow example et_add_marker return only one marker object, then

https://gist.github.com/alessandro-aglietti/ff6c3adc3493ced96df0

```
var myMarkers = et_add_marker();
myMarkers.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setVisible(boolean)` or `setMap(null)`.
if you want any doc,here is the link
http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/google-maps-markers.html